# How can i change my font size in HTML5 for one line?

Tags: html

i want to change the font size of only one line of code is there any way i can do this in HTML5 without changing all lines? i use visual code studio, thank you.

Comment: Please, show us the code you have so far and what you have already tried to do. Also, read [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: Hi and welcome! Please share your code attempts in order that we can help you.

Answer (score 0):

You can use pseudo elements specifically the ::first-line element selects the first line. Example:
p::first-line { color: red};

It means the first line of a paragraph text will be changed to red.